# How to write it on ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, calculate-values, soil, formula

I just started using the Raster Calculator, so I don't know how to build the formulas.

How can I do this?

I need to write both of these formulas:

[image]

D = is a raster file called "Slope_2"

P = 13

Answer (score 2):

First one (should be this, or about this but I didn't test it):

```
SquareRoot(Power(P,2) + Power((D/100.0) + P),2)
```

Second one, you can figure it out now based on the above code.

I would recommend that you do the 2 calculations separately so that you can verify each one.

Just replace P with 13 and d with "Slope_2", you do that by double-clicking the open layer in Raster Calculator. You can also see some of the Math operators available in raster calculator by examining the right side.

If none of these functions satisfy you in the future, look into the "Math" toolbox, or better yet, start using python with ArcPy.Raster(). There are also some local functions available in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst

Comment: P is 13 so P squared is 169, that makes the first equation SquareRoot(169 + Power((D/100.0) + P,2) **)** - you misplaced the closing parenthesis. ArcPy.Raster() is case sensitive, it's arcpy.Raster(). Minor bugs in the scheme of things though, +1 anyway.